# I have an error when clicking on the second page in the navbar with express nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I hope I can explain: my situation is the following, I have a navbar that shows 3 pages but the page when I click it sends me an automatic 404 that was not found.
my app.js

```
import { Router } from 'express'

//Router1
const router = Router()
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
router.get("/page2", (req, res) => {
  res.render("page2");
});
router.post('/tasks/add', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('saved')
});
router.get("/edit", (req, res) => {
  res.render('edit');
});
//Router 2
//instanciamos router

//
app.use("/",router);
export default router;
```

The problem is that I have already created the pages: page 2 and page 3, now the problem is that it does not send me to the page. I hope you can help me :(

my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Virtual Library</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/page2">Add Boks</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/page3">Books</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

my app.js

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";
import { create } from "express-handlebars";
import indexRoutes from "./routes/tasks.routes";

const app = express();

// settings
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  create({
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
    defaulLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs",
  }).engine
);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
// middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// routes
app.use(indexRoutes);

// public route
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).render("404");
});


export default app;
```

Comment: is the URL for the 404 call as you expected? (check developer tools, network section)... does that URL open when you try to open it in a new tab?

Comment: Can you post the full code of `app.js`?

Comment: @lpizzinidev done add app.js

Comment: @Akber Iqbal the page that I expect in the menu is page 2 and not the 404 error